# Reformat dataset in R into rows as levels and columns as range

Tags: r, dataset, format, levels

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
partyid            coninc
Ind,Near Dem       25926
Not Str Democrat   33333
Not Str Democrat   41667
Strong Democrat    69444
Ind,Near Dem       60185
Ind,Near Dem       50926
Ind,Near Dem       18519
Strong Democrat    3704
Strong Democrat    25926
Strong Democrat    18519
Not Str Republican 18519
Strong Democrat    18519
Not Str Democrat   18519
```

What I want to do is format the dataset into something like this:

```
partyid             0-50,000   50,000-100,000   100,000-150,000   >150,000
Strong Democrat     2344       3423             4342              54
Not Str Democrat    2643       934              ..
Ind, Near Dem       7656       343              ..
Ind, Near Rep       7655       833              .. 
Not Str Republican  2443       343
Strong Republican   3444       773
```

i.e Sort the rows by the levels of partyid variable and the columns by the count of range of coninc variable.

A `dput` of my data:

```
structure(list(partyid = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Strong Democrat", "Not Str Democrat", "Ind,Near Dem", "Ind,Near Rep", "Not Str Republican", "Strong Republican"), class = "factor"), coninc = c(25926L, 33333L, 41667L, 69444L, 60185L, 50926L, 18519L, 3704L, 25926L, 18519L, 18519L, 18519L, 18519L, 25926L, 18519L, 33333L, 25926L, 60185L, 69444L, 50926L)), .Names = c("partyid", "coninc"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that quite easily with the `plyr` package (as your sample data are a bit hard to read, I deleted the commas and spaces in `partyid`):

```
# creating sample data
dat <- structure(list(partyid = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Strong Democrat", "Not Str Democrat", "Ind,Near Dem", "Ind,Near Rep", "Not Str Republican", "Strong Republican"), class = "factor"), coninc = c(25926L, 33333L, 41667L, 69444L, 60185L, 50926L, 18519L, 3704L, 25926L, 18519L, 18519L, 18519L, 18519L, 25926L, 18519L, 33333L, 25926L, 60185L, 69444L, 50926L)), .Names = c("partyid", "coninc"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), class = "data.frame")

# summarising the data with plyr
require(plyr)
dat2 <- ddply(dat, .(partyid), summarise,
              zero = sum(coninc < 50001),
              fifty = sum(coninc > 50000 & coninc < 100001),
              hundred = sum(coninc > 100000 & coninc < 150001),
              hfifty = sum(coninc > 150000))
```

This results in the following output:

```
dat2 <- structure(list(partyid = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Strong Democrat", "Not Str Democrat", "Ind,Near Dem", "Ind,Near Rep", "Not Str Republican", "Strong Republican"), class = "factor"), zero = c(6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), fifty = c(1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L), hundred = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hfifty = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("partyid", "zero", "fifty", "hundred", "hfifty"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I tried your code. However for each row, I get the same value i.e the total count of the level eg. for the top row I get: Strong Democrat 9117 9117 9117 9117. 9117 is total number of rows in the dataset where partyid = "Strong Democrat". That number should be broken down into ranges between 0-50000, 50000-100000 and so on.

Comment: Not really. All I'm getting is only NAs. Somehow I think length() should work as sum() should add all the coninc values that corresponds. But I'm using this function for the first time so..

Comment: That's strange because I get the correct output. I added my output to my answer. Can you include a part of your with `dput` in your question? You can do that with `dput(head(datasetname,20))`

Comment: I updated my answer. Now I used your sample dat from your `dput`. I also included a `dput` of the resulting dataframe. As you can see, it gives the correct results.

Comment: My bad. You're solution works perfectly. It was just that I had missing values (NA) in my original dataset with >40,000 rows. That was causing the problem. Thanks Man... you saved my day. Cheers !

Comment: Strange, I thought libraries like "plyr" would handle 'NA' values effortlessly !

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `cut` and `table` in base R:

```
dat$cat <- cut(dat$coninc, breaks = c(0, 50000, 100000, 150000, Inf),
               labels = c("< 50K", "50K - 100K", "100K - 150K", "> 150K"))
table(dat$partyid, dat$cat)
#                     
#                      < 50K 50K - 100K 100K - 150K > 150K
#   Strong Democrat        6          1           0      0
#   Not Str Democrat       3          0           0      0
#   Ind,Near Dem           2          4           0      0
#   Ind,Near Rep           2          1           0      0
#   Not Str Republican     1          0           0      0
#   Strong Republican      0          0           0      0
```